# For line Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I'm making an iOS code interpreter. I have all the checking done but as of now you can only enter one command. I want the user to be able to enter multiple commands into a UITextView. What I plan do with the text view is pass each line the my IF statement line.

Does anyone know of a way to say, pass each line one by one into a if statement line?

```
- (IBAction)runCommad:(id)sender {

    //Alert
    NSString *alertCheck = @"alert(";
    NSRange alertCheckRange = [code.text rangeOfString : alertCheck];
    //Logger
    NSString *logCheck = @"log(";
    NSRange logCheckRange = [code.text rangeOfString : logCheck];

    if (alertCheckRange.location != NSNotFound) {
//If the compiler sees alert()...
        NSString *commandEdit;
        commandEdit = code.text;
        commandEdit = [commandEdit stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"alert(" withString:@""];
        commandEdit = [commandEdit stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Syn0" message:commandEdit delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }else  if (logCheckRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        //If the compiler sees log()...
        NSString *commandEdit;
        commandEdit = code.text;
        commandEdit = [commandEdit stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"log(" withString:@""];
        commandEdit = [commandEdit stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
        logFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", logFile,commandEdit];
        logTextView.text = logFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what  you're asking here; can you edit your question to expand your explanation somewhat? Are you writing an application to interpret "iOS code", or are you writing a program on iOS which interprets code in some unspecified language? Is the problem just that you have the text in a textview and want to split it into lines, or are you asking how to *execute* the code represented by those lines? Doing the latter will range from easy to  impossible, depending on what that target language is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get your string components to evaluate:

```
NSString *text = [textView text];    
NSArray *components = [text componentsSeperatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

You can't use a switch with a string, so you'll need to check for each case with an if:

```
for (NSString *string in components)
{
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"The first string you're matching"])
    {
        //Do something because you found first string
    }

    if([string isEqualToString:@"The second string you're matching"])
    {
        //Do something else
    }
}
```

That's the idea.

Comment: This approach looks very clean.

Comment: Works amazing! Now to figure out exactly what its doing :P //Rhetorical//

Comment: You might try `-[NSString enumerateLinesUsingBlock:]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions, first if you are comfortable with blocks you can use `NSString`'s:

```
(void)enumerateLinesUsingBlock:(void (^)(NSString *line, BOOL *stop))block
```

This method will call the block passing it each line in the original string in order. If you want to stop before processing each line you set `stop` to `YES`.

Alternatively you can use `NSString`'s:

```
(NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

This will break a string up into components based on `separator`. Use this in a `for` enumeration:

```
for(NSString *nextLine in [originalString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"])
{
   // process nextLine, break from loop to stop before processing each line
}
```

Comment: I added code examples. How would I implant your way into my code?